# write vs write-line in LISP

Tags: lisp

I am getting started with LISP and write the following program

```
(write-line "hello world")
(print "hello world print")
(write "hello world write")
```

for which I get the following output

```
hello world

"hello world print" "hello world write"
```

I guess `write` and `print` return string object so whats the type thats being returned by `write-line` why this didn't have quotations.

[Link](http://rextester.com/live/TWMAE62285) to my work-space

Comment: It looks like the latter 2 preserve quotations, while the former doesn't. I don't think it makes much sense to reason about what the type is, since it's being printed, not returned.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`write-line`/ `write-string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_stg.htm) official documentation it returns its argument. What you see it the side effect (printing). Usually you will also see the return if top level in a REPL:

```
> (write-line "hello world")
; hello world (printed)
;==> "hello world" (returned)
```

Note that [`write`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm#print) is not limited to printing strings as they take any CL object and `prin1`, `print`, `pprint`, and `princ` are just `write` with some dynamic settings predefined.